# Standard C function names

Tags: c

Is there any rationale for the abbreviated way standard C functions are written? For example, `malloc()` is short for 'memory allocation'. `sprintf()` is 'string print formatted'. Neither of these names are very good at telling you what the function actually does. It never occurred to me how terrible some of these abbreviated function names are until recently when I had to teach a new intern many of these functions.

When the language was being developed, was there any reason `malloc()` was chosen over `memAllocate()` or something similar? My best guess would be that they more closely resemble UNIX commands, but that doesn't feel like the right answer.

Comment: Bytes used to be expensive.

Comment: I think it's because `C` was written before tab completion was any good and that defined the `C` "culture" to use short function names.

Comment: Probably also to make the function names easier to type.

Comment: C is a product of the early 1970s and it shows.  Once upon a time, external names were limited to 8 characters or so, not just for saving keystrokes, but because space in compilers and linkers was really that tight.  That hasn't been the case for over 30 years now, but nobody's going to go rename everything in the standard library just to make it read better.

Comment: @JohnBode: `s/read better/more work to type/`

Comment: For reference, the 1972-vintage PDP-11/45 had a max memory capacity of 256K with an add-on MMU.  Space really was that tight, and vowels tended to be the first casualty.  Fortran code of the same era tends to be just as terse, although that's probably more to do with having to use punch cards as anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/keywords_and_identifiers.html -

> The problem is that there was never any guarantee that more than a
>   certain number of characters would be checked when names were compared
>   for equality—in Old C this was eight characters, in Standard C this
>   has changed to 31.

Basically, in the past (long while back) you could only count on the the first eight characters for uniqueness in a function name. So, you end up with a bunch of short names for the core functions.

Answer (score 3):

As [Neal Stephenson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neal_Stephenson) wrote about Unix in [*In the Beginning Was the Command Line*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Beginning..._Was_the_Command_Line),

> Note the obsessive use of abbreviations and avoidance of capital letters; this is a system invented by people to whom repetitive stress disorder is what black lung is to miners. Long names get worn down to three-letter nubbins, like stones smoothed by a river.

The first version of Unix and the first C compiler were written using versions of [`ed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor)).  Not `vi`, not `emacs`, not anything resembling an IDE, but the line-based `ed`.  There comes a point where reducing the number of keystrokes really does increase the number of SLOC you can write per day, when you're inventing something brand-new and writing it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The historical justification is of course that historically the C standard only required implementations to distinguish the initial 6 characters of external identifier names. This allowance was removed in C99. However, users of the C language generally:

- Aim to write source code in such a way that it fits in a reasonable number of columns, usually 80 or fewer, which is difficult with long identifier names.
- Type identifier names with a keyboard, which is difficult and a waste of time when the identifiers are long.
- Tend to prefer high information density and signal-to-noise ratio in source code.